# Indexing Strategy for the query performance

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning, performance, covering-index, performance-tuning

I have a question on indexing strategy as i am trying to do indexing for a database.

I understand the basic indexing strategy which are:

- Clustered index on PrimaryKey
- Add Non Clustered index for other columns as per requirement.
- Should have indexes for WHERE/JOIN/GROUP BY/ORDER BY columns
- Covering indexes for columns to avoid keylookup.
- Check the workload and avoid adding too many indexes
- Index Foreign Keys
- Index any other unique keys etc..
  I still have some questions and i couldn't find an exact answer to my questions.

Here is an example of a table that i have.

```
USE [DEMODB]
GO


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee_Header](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PageId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Dept] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [DeptName] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [SubUnit] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [ShiftType] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [ReportDate] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [ReportTime] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [AccessNumber] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [AccessOnAfterDate] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [AccessOnAfterTime] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [EmpBand] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [WorkSite] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [Location_FieldValue] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [Location_Description] [varchar](256) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee_Header] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

As you can see `[Id]` is the `primary key` here.`[PageID]` is the `foreign key` and it is not unique.
There are few queries which uses `where`clause on `[Dept],[SubUnit], [ShiftType] and [ReportDate]'.

One query displays columns  `[Dept] and [ShiftType]` and other query displays `[Dept],[ReportDate],[ReportTime],[EmpBand]`

1. I am confused as to how to create NonClustered indexes with Include
   columns so that same indexes can be used to both queries Or
2. should i create separate clustered indexes for where each columns
3. then create a separate single NonClustered index with PrimaryKey
       column as unique column and all the display columns in the include
       section.
4. Should i just keep the display columns in the keycolumn section?

Most of the examples available shows querying to a single table with an Id and one or more select column.
Can someone help me to understand how you approach similar situations?

I created two indexes as shown below.

First one is for the where clauses.I have all the where clause fields added as key columns in this non clustered index

`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_Employee_Filters] ON [dbo].[Employee_Header]
(
    [Dept] ASC,
    [SubUnit] ASC,
    [ShiftType] ASC,
    [ReportDate] ASC,
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO`

The second one is for the select columns.Some of the select columns are already part of the first index so i have only two columns that needs to be covered.
So i added them as Include fields with Id(Primary key field) as the key column.

`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_Employee_Include_Fields] ON [dbo].[Employee_Header]
(
    [Id] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ReportTime],
    [EmpBand]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO`

Still when i run and see the execution plan, i get the message that there is a missing index.

`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Employee_Header] ([ReportDate])
INCLUDE ([Id],[Dept],[ShiftType],[ReportTime],[EmpBand])`

I don't understand why query optimizer is suggesting to a date filed as key field and other fields in the include section.
I already have a Nonclustered index with `ReportDate` among other where fields.

Appreciate for sharing your approach.But can anyone answer/share your perspective on the specific example mentioned?

Comment: You should include the exact queries you're looking to add supporting indexes for. Once you add a given index, you can test your queries to see if the execution plan utilizes them or not to sanity check whether they're usable by each query.

Comment: @LowlyDBA.I have the select fields and where field which is being used in two queries.How do you approach/or what combination of non clustered indexes u will create?I will check the execution plan to see if the indexes i created is used or not.But before that i need to know for where clause i should have this index and for select fields i should have this covering index?I am trying to understand how seasoned DBA's like you approach this ?

Comment: For all we know one of your queries is using a function, which *could* materially affect indexing. I would not approach this unless I knew the queries I was creating indexes for (a word-problem summary of the queries doesn't count).

Answer (score 2):

For a general-purpose or OLTP design, the initial index design should be more conservative:

- Clustered index on Primary Key.
- Unique non-clustered index any other unique keys.
- Index supporting each Foreign Key (where not already covered above).

Then, for very large tables, consider changing to a Nonclustered Primary Key and a Clustered Columnstore.

Then additional indexes *as needed* for optimization of the actual workload.  These can be indexes with included columns, filtered indexes, non-clustered columnstore indexes, or indexed views on a case-by-case basis.